# rails 4 - ldap authentication and user objects without database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, authentication, activemodel

I have an app where users log in and the LDAP server is used to authenticate them. That part I have down, but the hiccup comes when dealing with the users and multiple sessions. 
When a user is authenticated I create a new user object from a user model that inherits from ActiveModel, saves their name and email from the LDAP entry. This is done in `sessions_controller` with user as an instance variable. i.e. `@user = User.new`
However when `current_user` in `application_controller` checks for the user object, it's value is `nil`. 
I'm guessing this is a scoping issue where the application controller can't see the instance variable in session controller's value. 
Without using a database, how could I handle saving this minimal info about a user and have it persist through out their session? 
Before when using a class variable `@@user` and setting it in `application_controller` other users were only able to log in one at a time...
Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You might want to checkout something like https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable to avoid recreating all the authentication/current user code.

Comment: when i checked that out, it didn't have a good way of persisting user info without a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your User object is small, you can store it in the session.

```
class SessionController < ApplicationController
  def authenticate
    # Handle LDAP-auth and we now have a user
    #   ldap_authenticated? should be true
    #   ldap_user contains relevant info from LDAP

    session[:user] = User.new(email: ldap_user.email) if ldap_authenticated?
  end
end


module ApplicationHelper
  # Use this to access the current user everywhere in the app
  def current_user
    session[:user]
  end
end
```

Comment: I'll try this out, how would I access the `User` object attributes? like `session[:user].email`?

Comment: I'd use something like `current_user.email`

Comment: Nevermind figured it out, you access it like a hash of course lol `session[:user]["email"]`, thanks a ton!